# MySQL error: 'Table is specified twice both as a target for INSERT and as separate source of data'

Tags: mysql, sql

I run this query but it gives me error just like in the title:

**[PROBLEM 1]**

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity)
VALUES((SELECT max(IdClient) + 1 FROM Clients), '--New--')
```

I have tried to solve it with a subquery like that:

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity)
VALUES
    (
        (SELECT maxClient FROM
        (SELECT max(IdClient) + 1 maxClient FROM Clients)) subquery,
    '--New--' 
    )
```

but it doesn't work. Could anybody help me, please?

**UPDATE**

**[PROBLEM 1 SOLUTION]**

Finally I tested the VirCom query and it worked but including the specific column names:

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity)
SELECT max(IdClient) + 1, '--New--' FROM Clients
```

**[NEW PROBLEM 2]**

But I have a new problem, if I run this query with other "subquery", how could I do it the query, please?. This is an example

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity, Country)
SELECT max(IdClient) + 1, '--New--' FROM Clients,
SELECT IdCountry FROM Country WHERE Country = 'SPAIN'
```

Could anybody help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Wardiam

Answer (score 1):

I tested that with query:

```
INSERT INTO Clients SELECT MAX(IdClient) + 1, '--New--' FROM Clients;
```

And it works )

Comment: Sorry my bad i gave the programming thought din revive that there is a sequence of SQL query execution step by step so first the subquery of fetching will take place then the insert. So its not both at the same time hence it works

Comment: Thanks VirCom, I tested your query and it works but I need to include into Clients Table the specific column names because this table has 20 fields.

Comment: It could be a problem .... Or you should pass all required arguments in SELECT statement or ...
Is it must be a single statement ? Is it possible to implement it's as single transaction or to close whole code in stored procedure ?
And why not to use autoincrement ? Is it not primary key of that table ?

Comment: I prefer don't use autoincrement.

Comment: Maybe that:

INSERT INTO Clients
SELECT
 MAX(cl.IdClient) + 1,
 '--New--',
 co.IdCountry
FROM Clients AS cl, Country AS co
WHERE
 co.Country = 'SPAIN'

But i think it's not very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it!  Define an auto-increment column in the table and let the database handle this for you:

```
create table clients (
    idclient int auto_increment primar key,
    entity ?,
    . . .
);
```

Then, just leave it out so a new value appears:

```
insert into clients (Entity)
    values ('--New--');
```

Your version is subject to race conditions (where different threads end up with the same maximum value).  It could also require scanning the entire table.